# Compare Complex Objects

Tags: c#, object, compare

I need to write a comparer that compares complex objects of various type, I wrote some code but it seems too long to me , so is there any other way of good comparison between two complex objects?

My code:

```
class CompareObjOfType
{
    private static int _totalFalseCount;

    public static bool CompareObjectsOfType(Type T, object source, object target)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if ((source == null) && (target == null))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((source == null) ^ (target == null))
        {
            _totalFalseCount++;
            return false;
        }

        if (T.IsValueType || (T == typeof(string)))
        {
            if (T == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                if (!(((DateTime)source).ToUniversalTime().Equals(((DateTime)target).ToUniversalTime())))
                {
                    _totalFalseCount++;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (T == typeof(string))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)source) ^ string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)target))
                {
                    _totalFalseCount++;
                    return false;
                }
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)source) && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)target)))
                {
                    _totalFalseCount++;
                    return false;
                }

                if (!(((string)source).Equals((string)target)))
                {
                    _totalFalseCount++;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(source.ToString().Equals(target.ToString())))
                {
                    _totalFalseCount++;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var properties = T.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;

                if (propertyType.IsArray || propertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var sourceValue = property.GetValue(source);
                    var targetValue = property.GetValue(target);

                    if ((sourceValue == null) && (targetValue == null))
                    {
                        result = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ((sourceValue == null) ^ (targetValue == null))
                    {
                        _totalFalseCount++;
                        result = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var sourceCount = ((IList)sourceValue).Count;
                    var targetCount = ((IList)targetValue).Count;

                    if (sourceCount != targetCount)
                    {
                        _totalFalseCount++;
                        result = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < sourceCount; i++)
                    {
                        Type elementType = propertyType.IsArray
                                               ? propertyType.GetElementType()
                                               : propertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                        result = CompareObjectsOfType(elementType, ((IList)sourceValue)[i],
                                                      ((IList)targetValue)[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result = CompareObjectsOfType(propertyType, property.GetValue(source), property.GetValue(target));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you should head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should call `GetType()` (and/or use generics) instead of forcing the user to pass the type.

Comment: You will choke on `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: I would rather add in an ID or Name field in the Class / Struct and use that for comparison (if possible)

Comment: This seems to simple to me.

Comment: What if I have a a Property that is List from custom ref objects that have inside them other custome ref type and so on until there is something that can be compared like int,long,double,string,float etc.?

Comment: In that case implementing IComparer won't be a good idea because i'll have to implement IComparer for every custome type

Comment: Do not try to use reflection or `typeof` to detect types at runtime, use generics.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code a lot in my tests. Its not perfect by no means but might be good enough.  Note, the ignore params argument can contain a list of property names that you don't want to compare.

```
    public static void AssertArePropertiesEqual<T>(T expectedObj, T actualObj, params string[] ignore) where T : class
    {
        if (expectedObj != null && actualObj != null)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedObj, actualObj);
                return;
            }
            var ignoreList = new List<string>(ignore);
            foreach (var pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (ignoreList.Contains(pi.Name)) continue;
                var selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(expectedObj, null);
                var toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(actualObj, null);
                var selfValueDate = selfValue as DateTime?;
                var toValueDate = toValue as DateTime?;

                if (selfValueDate.HasValue && toValueDate.HasValue)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs((selfValueDate.Value - toValueDate.Value).TotalSeconds) < 1,
                                  string.Format("The compare of [{0}] properties failed. Expected Date:{1}  Actual Date: {2}", pi.Name,
                                                selfValueDate, toValueDate));
                }
                else
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(selfValue, toValue, string.Format("The compare of [{0}] properties failed.", pi.Name));
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedObj, actualObj);
    }
```

Comment: It looks good with a few changes , but I don't need the message box that Debug.Assert is showing. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IComparer.aspx). There is an example on msdn and a lot of examples on the world wide web.

All you need to check is if the first object is semantically considered to be **less than**, **equal to** or **greater than** the second object.

You can then easily order your objects in LINQ queries or wherever you need them to be ordered.

However, it might be better to re-think the design of your classes. Such extensive comparison (as in your code) is rarely needed.

---

If you only need to check for equality (not **less than** or **greater than**), then an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.aspx) comparer is enough, as commented by Kris.

Comment: I think he rather needs an IEqualityComparer, or even get an understanding of inheritance and overriding `object.Equals(object)`